# Is it possible to add a Bezel/Border to the screen saver mode on retropie?

Tags: retropie

Is it possible to add a Bezel/Border to the screen saver mode on retropie? I have bezels for each game installed, but when the screen savers come on the black bars are on the sides and id prefer to not have to stretch the videos to get rid of them. Even if I just make one custom bezel to display during the screen saver mode that would be great! Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You would need to modify something as that is not possible with the default retropie. A modified version of retropie may have a feature like that, but there aren't many different forks of retropie.